# One time Login with Jquerymobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm developing hybrid mobile application using PhonGap, with jquery mobile,I have created simple login and one page, I want to use one time login, currently user need to enter user name and password every time he/she login to the system.What is the strategy to add one time login? I would really appreciate if some one can help me to understand this

Thank you in advance

Comment: You could use localStorage or a WebSQL database? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Comment: I'm using localStorage,Still user gets login window,I do not want show the login window after user login to the system unless he/she logout from the app

Comment: @udeshikaperera Then you must have a bug of some kind. localStorage is probably the best solution for this (I know as I've done it myself). A key set in localStorage will persist until such time as it's deleted or cleared.

Comment: Thank you, I found the problem, as you said it was localStorage issue,It was a my mistake

Answer (score 1):

Create Unique Login id for every user login and maintain the session using login id.it will help user only one time login using

```
$uniqueid =md5(uniqid());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should post some code to help understanding your problem. Anyways, you could call a function on the event "pagebeforeshow" that shows the login (popup?page?) if you have not found the localstorage variable, and does not show the login otherwise.

Hope this helps a bit.